# trying to read midi controller device name using winmm

Tags: windows, midi, freepascal

Long term goal, build software to implement midi control surface as a user interface for industrial control applications by using a prebuilt midi controller instead of building and wiring a custom control panel. Short term goal, read the name of the midi device plugged into the computer. Immediate problem, the compiler says 'illegal qualifier, szPname". I believe that szPname is a subset of the caps structure but I don't understand how to get to it.

I am using implementing winmm from FreePascal on a windows 10 machine.

here is my current code...

```
program asd;  
uses mmSystem;  
var  
  caps: ^MIDIINCAPS;  
begin  
  writeln(midiInGetNumDevs());  
  midiInGetDevCaps(0,caps,SizeOf(MIDIINCAPS));  
  writeln(caps.szPname);  
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse62.html) says:

> **Error: Illegal qualifier**
>
> One of the following is happening:
>
> - You’re trying to access a field of a variable that is not a record.
> - You’re indexing a variable that is not an array.
> - You’re dereferencing a variable that is not a pointer.

In this case, `caps` is a pointer, so you must dereference it before you can access the record fields:

```
WriteLn(caps^.szPname);
```

(Other compilers can automatically dereference pointers to records. Apparently, FreePascal cannot.)

You also need to allocate memory for `caps`. (Or don't use a pointer.)

Comment: Thanks, That seems to have worked. It compiles without errors. Now I'm off to learn 'Runtime error 216"

Comment: I can get it to compile but I always get the same response when I try to run it. "Runtime error 216 at $00401EAD $00401EAD $00406261 $00401471 $00406621. I have compiled and run on two different machines and get the exact same results every time regardless of which machine it was compiled on or which machine it was run on.